# What is the difference between Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, soft-question, self-learning

What is the difference between Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry ?

Many of the theorems in Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry have a geometric interpretation.

Why both  are not same ?

Note: **I'm new on these two topics**

Comment: Commutative algebra is only the affine (and local) part of algebraic geometry. For instance, the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ is not an object of commutative algebra, it belongs to algebraic geometry.

Comment: Commutative algebra is to algebraic geometry, as multivariable calculus is to differential geometry.

Comment: To add to Martin's point: There is an anti-equivalence of categories between the category of affine schemes and the category of commutative unital rings. The equivalence is given by associating a ring its spectrum and intrinsically defined structure sheaf and taking global sections of the structure sheaf in the other direction. Since the objects of interest in algebraic geometry are schemes, i.e. ringed spaces which locally look like affine schemes, this is what is meant when saying something like 'commutative algebra is the affine part of algebraic geometry.'

Comment: Another addition: The study of modules over a ring $A$ is equivalent to the study of quasi-coherent sheaves on $\text{Spec}A$, in the sense that there is an anti-equivalence of categories.

Answer (score -2):

Algebraic geometry classically studies the zeros of multivariate polynomials and uses techniques such as abstract algebra to solve geometric problems on these sets of zeros. Commutative algebra is essentially the study of the rings that appear in algebraic number theory and algebraic geometry.